# Error creating bean with name 'sassionFactory' defined in class path resource [resources/spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

**Error Message**
[Please click for error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csn2k.png)

I am looking for the solution of this error for the last 2 days but couldn't find. Please help me solve this. I also check other similar posts but unable to find a solution.

**BEAN FILE**

'''

```
package model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;

    public Student(int id, String name, String address, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;

    }
    geter/seter
```

'''

**DAO INTERFACE**

'''

```
package DAO;

import java.util.List;

import model.Student;



public interface StudentDAO {
    public int save(Student st);

    public boolean update(Student st);

    public boolean delete(Student st);

    public Student findByPK(int pk);

    public List<Student> findAllUsingHQL(Student st);

    public List<Student> findAllUsingCriteria(Student st);

}
```

'''

**DAO IMPLEMENTATION**

'''

```
package DAO;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

import model.Student;

public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {
    private HibernateTemplate ht;

    public HibernateTemplate getHt() {
        return ht;
    }

    public void setHt(HibernateTemplate ht) {
        this.ht = ht;
    }

    public int save(Student st) {

        return (Integer) ht.save(st);
    }

    public boolean update(Student st) {
        ht.update(st);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean delete(Student st) {
        ht.delete(st);
        return false;
    }

    public Student findByPK(int pk) {
        Student std = ht.get(Student.class, pk);
        return std;
    }

    public List<Student> findAllUsingHQL(Student st) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Student> list = (List<Student>) ht.find("from Student");
        return list;
    }

    public List<Student> findAllUsingCriteria(Student st) {
        DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Student.class);
        List<Student> list = (List<Student>) ht.findByCriteria(dc);
        return list;
    }

}
```

'''
**main method***
Currently only looking for save operation.
'''

```
package test;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import DAO.StudentDAOImpl;
import model.Student;


public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ConfigurableApplicationContext ap = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml");
            StudentDAOImpl dao = (StudentDAOImpl) ap.getBean("dao");
            int l = dao.save(new Student(2, "ravi", "ravi.ymail.com", "goa"));
            System.out.println(l);
            ap.close();
        } catch (BeansException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

'''

**spring.xml**

'''

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
            "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="bds" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="74484" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="15" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Create SessionFactory -->

    <bean id="sassionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="bds" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>model.Student</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="hibernateTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sassionFactory"></property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="dao" class="DAO.StudentDAOImpl">
        <property name="ht" ref="hibernateTemplate"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

'''

Comment: Your config is borked, you are mixing hibernate3 setup classes with hibernate4 setup classes and you are probably using Hibernate 5. Also don't use `HibernateTemplate` just use the `SessionFactory` directly.

Comment: I have changed to hibernate3 but still getting the same error. I have a task to use HibernateTemplate that why I'm using it.

Comment: Don't use `HibernateTEmplate` as that is deprecated and will be removed. And again using hibernate3 classes when using hibernate4 or 5 isn't going to work. Also you get an exception add it to the question (not as an image but as text and the **full** stacktrace not jsut a snippet).